# Set DateTime parameter to the Date ONLY

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime column in my database and want to set it to the Date ONLY (1/1/1900). But the time is always added. Here is what I've tried.

```
string dtstr = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1).Date.ToString("d");

orderRow.OrderDateSent = Convert.ToDateTime(dtstr);
```

Comment: What is the type of `OrderDataSent`? Similarly, why you're converting `dtstr` `.ToDateTime` when it already is an instance of `DateTime`?

Comment: What about this doesn't work? It is a strange way of doing it, you could just do `orderRow.OrderDateSent = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);` If you want to actually change the data type of the column in the DB, then you need to execute `ALTER TABLE [Order] ALTER COLUMN OrderDateSent date;`

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for the table.

Comment: I tried orderRow.OrderDateSent = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1); and it gets set to {1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM}. I want only the 1/1/1900

Comment: The short answer - you can't. `DateTime` has a time (it just does, you can't avoid that). Thus you need to do one of two things. a) Change the database to store dates, not datetimes. Or b) `ToString` the date to _just_ get the date component (not the time).

Comment: I used this code and even though it gets the time component also, the database column only gets set to the date value. Weird.                     orderRow.OrderDateSent = System.DateTime.Parse("1-1-1900");

Comment: `I used this code and even though it gets the time component also, the database column only gets set to the date value.` No it doesn't. You might think it does, but it doesn't. You are confusing how it is stored vs how it is _displayed_. They aren't the same thing. We can't help without seeing the `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: In .NET 6 (preview 4), two long-awaited types have been introduced as part of the core library. `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` allow developers to represent either the date or time portion of a DateTime. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/

Answer (score -1):

You can use date.[ToShortDateString() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-5.0) to store only the date part in a string variable. With regards to the format of your database column, you need to provide more details and it is outside the scope of c#. It would depend on the schema of your table and type of the column.

Answer (score -2):

I used this code and even though it gets the time component also, the database column only gets set to the date value. Weird.                     orderRow.OrderDateSent = System.DateTime.Parse("1-1-1900");

Comment: It's not weird at all: both `date` and `datetime` in SQL map to `DateTime`

Comment: `System.DateTime.Parse("1-1-1900")` is exactly the same as `new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)` I would be very surprised if they had a different outcome.